Feast's FileSource path gets prefixed with local directory on Windows, causing path errors
I am trying to use Feast's FileSource to load a .parquet file stored in a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket, as part of the feast tutorial: https://github.com/feast-dev/feast-workshop/blob/main/module_0/README.md#step-1-fetch-features-for-batch-scoring-method-1
The path field of FileSource is set to a GCS URL. However, I’m encountering an issue on Windows 11, where the GCS path gets prefixed with the local project directory path, resulting in an invalid file path.
Here is my code:
from feast import FileSource

driver_stats = FileSource(
    name="driver_stats_source",
    path="gs://feast-workshop-feast-workshop/driver_stats.parquet",
    timestamp_field="event_timestamp",
    created_timestamp_column="created",
    description="A table describing the stats of a driver based on hourly logs",
    owner="test2@gmail.com",
)

When I run the script (test_fetch.py), I get the following error:
OSError: An error occurred while calling the read_parquet method registered to the pandas backend. 
Original Message: [WinError 123] Failed querying information for path 'C:/Users/jofwf/PycharmProjects/feast-workshop/module_0/client_gcp/gs:/feast-workshop-feast-workshop/driver_stats.parquet'. 
Detail: [Windows error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

What I Tried:

Verified that the GCS file path (gs://feast-workshop-feast-workshop/driver_stats.parquet) exists and is accessible using gcloud storage objects list.
Tried running the script on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), but the same issue occurs. The path is also incorrectly prefixed with the local directory path in WSL.

Environment Details:

OS: Windows 11

Python Version: 3.10

Feast Version: 0.31.1

Dask Version: 2023.1.0


Questions:

Is this a known issue with Feast on Windows / does it occur on linux, too?
How can I ensure the path is treated as a remote GCS path instead of being prefixed with the local directory? Both for using plain Windows 11 and WSL 2.

